# How to update the image name from ajax response in dropzone?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I would like to update the image name once file got uploaded  and on success i have to change the image name in dropzone field. how to do it. I am using http://dropzone.js. I have tried with the following code but i am not sure  how to append the image name once file got uploaded and response name into drozpone field

```
var fileList = new Array;
var i =0;
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
addRemoveLinks: true ,
 maxFiles: 5,
 acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
 url: "<?php echo site_url('settings_pro/work_picture_upload'); ?>", 

    init: function() {
        thisDropzone = this;

        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
    alert("No more files please!");
     this.removeFile(file);
     this.addFile(file);
});

        this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
                console.log(file);
                var file_name = file.name;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo base_url('settings_pro/delete_image'); ?>',
                    data: { 'filename': file_name },
                    success: function(report) {
                        console.log(report);
                    },
                    error: function(report) {
                        console.log(report);
                    }
                });
            });


        $.get('<?php echo base_url('settings_pro/get_picture'); ?>', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key,value){
                //alert(data);
            //var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
            var mockFile = { name: value.name};
            thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
            thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, 
            value.path);
            });
        });

         this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {

             alert("hi");
        // event when files are successfully uploaded
        // you can return a response string and process it here through 'response'
    });


    this.on("success", function(file, response) {
    //  fileList[serverFileName] = {"serverFileName" : response.name, "fileName" : file.name };

    file.serverId = response; 
    //$('#dz-preview').html('<img src="" width="200" height="200" alt="<?php //echo $empNameFull; ?>">');

//  location.reload();


});

     this.on('complete', function () {});
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `console.log(report);` output?

Comment: I need to append the image. its just deleting the image